# Scrapy return/pass data to another module

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, python-3.5

Hi I'm wondering how could I pass scraping result which is pandas file to module which created creating spider.

```
import mySpider as mspider
def main():
    spider1 = mspider.MySpider()
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(spider1)
    process.start()
    print(len(spider1.result))
```

Spider:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'MySpider'
    allowed_domains = config.ALLOWED_DOMAINS
    result = pd.DataFrame(columns=...)

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(url=...,headers=config.HEADERS, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        *...Some Code of adding values to result...*
        print("size: " + str(len(self.result)))
```

Printed value in main method is **0** when in parse method is **1005**. Could you tell me how should I pass value between.

I would like to do that cause I'm running multiple spiders. After they finish scraping I'll merge and save to file.

**SOLUTION**

```
def spider_closed(spider, reason):
    print("Size" + str(len(spider.result)))

def main():
    now = datetime.now()
    spider1 = spider.MySpider()
    crawler_process = CrawlerProcess()
    crawler = crawler_process.create_crawler(spider1)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    crawler_process.crawl(spider1)
    crawler_process.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for this behavior is the asynchronous nature of Scrapy itself. The `print(len(spider1.result))` line would be executed before the `.parse()` method is called.

There are multiple ways to wait for the spider to be finished. I would do the [`spider_closed` signal](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed):

```
from scrapy import signals


def spider_closed(spider, reason):
    print(len(spider.result))

spider1 = mspider.MySpider()

crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
crawler = crawler_process.create_crawler()

crawler.signals.connect(spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

crawler.crawl(spider1)
crawler_process.start()
```

Comment: I have problem with 
crawler = crawler_process.create_crawler()
should it be : crawler = crawler_process.create_crawler(spider1).
And is process.signals -> crawler_process?

Comment: @MrNetroful yeah, it should be `crawler.signals.connect(spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)`

Comment: can I somehow check if crawler_process finished or still crawling spiders  count?

Comment: @MrNetroful there are all sorts of different signals in scrapy, engine_stopped might be something you need https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#engine-stopped. Thanks.